# what will be the PDF of magnitude and phase of this random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, central-limit-theorem

i have a random variable as shown in the figure and i tried to find the PDF of the magnitude and phase of this random variable using central limit theory as i mentioned , i know that if we have complex random variable with both real and imaginary part has a Gaussian distribution then the magnitude and phase will have Rayleigh and uniform distribution respectively but this is only if real and imaginary part of this complex R.V. are independent but in my case as shown that both real , imaginary part depend on the angle phi (R.V.) so what will be the solution in this case ?[image]